# Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 3.3

Tags: android, maven

I am trying to make android build using command
   ionic cordova build android 
  but I am facing error like

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 3.3. If using t
>           he gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\BAXA_POS\Development\tr
>           unk\Mobile\baxa_pos\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.1-all.zip

code in build.gradle is

```
    /*
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
*/

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

//task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
 //   gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
//}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*

    ELSE NOTHING! DON'T MESS WITH THE VERSION CODE IF YOU DON'T HAVE TO!

    else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
      def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
      // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
      // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
      // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
      if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
      } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
      }
    }
    */

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning' || task.name == 'validateSigningRelease') {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

Code for gradle-wrapper.properties

```
        #DATE
        distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
        distributionPath=wrapper/dists
        zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
        zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
        distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

I have tried everything like changing distributionUrl and changing default gradle version , but everytime I run android build command distributionUrl change itself to old one.Can anyone suggest me something for this, that can work in my case.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392464/8034839

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem after trying so many alternatives and i.e.

For those who use ionic, go to

```
[project name]/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js
```

on line 164 you will see the following:

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip';
```

This line is used to create your gradle-wrapper.properties, so any changes to the gradle-wrapper.properties won't matter. All you need to do is change the url to the latest version, sync the gradle and the problem is solved.

If you just want to change the gradle version in the Android studio, go to `File>settings>project` and change the gradle version. After you apply, it will sync the project and you are ready to build.

Comment: Best solution was based on your response. Set up the enviroment variable CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL to the desired URL and it will work.

Comment: @Andrew - this worked very well for me with Gradle 4.6 and Ionic.

Comment: I agree, setting `CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL` should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Andrew:i tried above solution from CLI  but after build android all changes are replaced can you tell me what the issue?

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem with cordova.

You need to edit the gradle version to the latest in these files.

```
platforms/android/app/build.gradle
platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js
platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/StudioBuilder.js
platforms/android/build.gradle
```

While I am writing this post, the latest version is a 4.10.2. Current versions can be found [here](https://gradle.org/releases/).

In */android/app/build.gradle* find this part of the code.

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.10.2'
}
```

In *GradleBuilder.js* find this part of the code.

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip';
```

In *StudioBuilder.js* find this part of the code.

```
  var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip';
```

In last file */android/build.gradle* we change the following line to actual version. Actual version for Android Gradle plugin you can find on [this side](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin).

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

Thanks Khaled Osman

Comment: this fixes my issue of gradle link keeps reverting to older one

Comment: Meanwhile instead of GradleBuilder.js and StudioBuilder.js the file ProjectBuilder.js exists.

Comment: @Juraj Kršák: i tried above code and but after build android from cli  all changes are reset can you tell me sir whats the issue?

Answer (score 7):

In Linux run these commands:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Put the export in the end of file.

```
export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL="https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip"
```

Run these command to load the new variable.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Check if the version of gradle in export url is your desire.

Comment: You save my day!

Answer (score 5):

if you're using cordova/phonegap go to

```
platforms/android/app/build.gradle
platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js
platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/StudioBuilder.js
```

and look for the old gradle version according to the error then replace it with the new one.

Answer (score 4):

For Ionic users:

After changing the URL everywhere (in the js, in the gradle file etc etc), it was still not working.

To make it work, I had to do this:

```
ionic cordova rm android
ionic cordova add android@latest
```

Remove the android platform then add it again.

Comment: this should be: `ionic cordova platform rm android` and `ionic cordova platform add android@latest`

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project->android->Wrapper->Gradle->Wrapper->Open gradle-wrapper.properties
 change your version:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

change this line:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Rebuild your application

Comment: sir i have tried build during build android changes are removed

Answer (score 1):

This is because the following code:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}
```

try commenting it. Then change your `gradle-wrapper.properties` to:

```
#Tue Jan 30 17:55:46 WIB 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: I have tried commenting this but same problem occured.

Comment: try removing `.gradle` directory inside your project.

Comment: removed .gradle , still not working .. everytime I try to make build using command 'ionic cordova build android ' , build.gradle and gradle-wrapper.properties file reloads  and change to earlier properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mac user then simply follow below steps

```
$ brew install gradle
```

Above command install the letest gradle

Then Check the version

```
$ gradle -v
```

Then change the gradle version of build.gradle file .

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Ionic 4 users:

Shilpi's Answer is correct except that the path for building gradle can now be found in:

```
[project name]/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/ProjectBuilder.js
```

Search for `distributionUrl`

Answer (score 0):

to Android studio I just cleaned subfolders in /app/.gradle

After that, gradle was able to build the wrapper correct version

Answer (score 0):

change gradle-wrapper.properties distributionUrl with latest gradle link

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this issue after cordova cli update **9** to **10** and with this upgrading Android Studio **4.0.0** to **4.0.1**.

I have not much modified Cordova Android app, and used

**cordova platforms rm android**

after that

**cordova platforms add android**

This commands updated my cordova android version too.

Older
"cordova-android": "^8.1.0"
Newest
"cordova-android": "^9.0.0"

Answer (score -1):

Please check you `path` variable for which gradle version.