# What is the real Android Studio Gradle Version?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In (Root) build.gradle Gradle Version is 3.1.3.

**(Root) build.gradle**

[image: (Root) build.gradle]

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

In *project-structure* the Gradle version is 4.4

**Project-Structure**

[image]

```
Gradle version 4.4
```

In Gradle-wrapper-properties distributionUrl's, the Gradle version is 4.4

**Gradle-Wrapper-Properties**

[image]

```
#Tue Jul 17 17:49:20 KST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

But I can build and I can run the application in the smartphone.

What is the real Gradle version?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to be clear about **three** things here:

- Gradle
- Android Gradle Plugin
- Gradle Wrapper

Specifically speaking,

- **Gradle** is a build tool which evolves independently of Android. Theoretically, Gradle can be used to build any kind of project, for example, a typical Java project, Android Project and even iOS project. It can also be integrated with any kind of IDE, for example, [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio), [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans), or [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29).

  By the time of writing, the latest Gradle version is 4.9, and you can always check its current version from [Gradle installation guide](https://gradle.org/install/). One of the great features of Gradle build tool is it supports [Custom Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html).
- **Android Gradle Plugin** The [Android Gradle Plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) is one such Gradle custom plugin. For the typical Android project, the version of this plugin can be configured in the top-level `build.gradle`.

  ```
  buildscript {
      ....
          dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
      }
      ....
  }
  ```

  For each version of this plugin, it requires a minimum Gradle version as listed in this page [gradle-plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) or see below mapping table for a quick information:

  [image]

  For example, Android Gradle Plugin version **3.1.0+** requires a minimal Gradle version **4.4** which can be configured via Android Studio.
- **Gradle Wrapper**. According to the official document [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)

  > The recommended way to execute any Gradle build is with the help of the Gradle Wrapper (in short just “Wrapper”). The Wrapper is a script that invokes a declared version of Gradle, downloading it beforehand if necessary. As a result, developers can get up and running with a Gradle project quickly without having to follow manual installation processes saving your company time and money.

  This wrapper can be configured from `gradle-wrapper.properties` under your project directory. For example,

  ```
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
  ```

  Or from the Android Studio GUI as said in your question:

  [image: Project Structure Configuration].

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing two different versions.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

Indicates the version of the Android Gradle plugin is 3.1.3. The other two fields are describing the version of the Gradle build system.

These can also be different, if you choose not to use the optional gradlew-wrapper (`gradlew`) tools. I highly recommend you do use them though. They make things much easier.

Answer (score 3):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

This refers to the Android plugin for Gradle.

```
Gradle version 4.4
```

This and all the other versions are for Gradle itself.

Gradle and the Android plugin for Gradle are two different pieces of software and so have different version numbers.