# Android studio 3.2.beta5 , Gradle version gradle-4.6-all.zip, Still Get Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.1.

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am using 
Android studio - **3.2.beta5**

Gradle version - **gradle-4.6-all.zip**
Getting Exception - 
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/vrushali/workspace/GradleForAndroidAndJava/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.6-all.zip

I am trying to run one task in groovy using  -

```
gradle -q putOnShoes
```

**1. Code i am trying to run :-**

```
task putOnSocks{ doLast{
    println "Putting on Socks" }
}

task putOnShoes{ dependsOn "PutOnSocks" doLast{
    println "Putting on Shoes.." }
 }
```

1.My Plugin is latest gradle. Any help would be appreciated 
Attaching screenshot below it would help:-

**2. Gradle version i am using :-**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Comment: Maybe try to understand the gradle versions from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392464/8034839