# My project not picking up class files defined in library module jar folder

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

I have added a library by going to `File-> New ->Import Module`, the library added successfully, there are around `8 jar` files added in this imported module, but in my app module i am unable to access these files.

Although i can easily access files that are available in library `src` folder.

These lines are added in library gradle file.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native", include: 'native.jar')
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile project(':myLibrary')
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':myLibrary'
```

If i perform these steps in a new project, i can access classes inside jar files from my `app module`, but in my current project they are not accessible.

I also tried deleting `android studio preference`, `invalidate cache and restart`, but nothing sees to be working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my current project they are not accessible.

The are not supposed to be accessible, because those dependency jars are not part of your app project.

If you want to have access to those jars depended by your library module `myLibrary`, you need to specify them inside your `app` project using

```
compile fileTree(dir: '../myLibrary/libs', include: '*.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: "../myLibrary/native", include: 'native.jar')
```

and change your `myLibrary` settings to be

```
provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
provided fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native", include: 'native.jar')
```

By doing above, you should be able to access your jars from your app module and there won't be any duplicate classes causing conflict.

Maybe it will be better to upgrade your Android Gradle Plugin to 3.0+.

Additional information about android gradle plugin versions:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392464/8034839
2. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies

Just quote the key explanations here for your information about `provided` and `compileOnly`:

> Gradle adds the dependency to the compile classpath only (that is, it is not added to the build output). This is useful when you're creating an Android module and you need the dependency during compilation, but it's optional to have it present at runtime.

For your library module, itself actually only requires its dependencies be in compile **classpath** if you don't package them into your library **.jar** or **.aar**. In this case, the application that uses this library needs to add those external jars depended by your library module because your library module did not package them (by using `compileOnly`) . And your application need those external jars be runtime available by using `compile`.

Comment: Thanks @shizhen, When i use `compileOnly` it returns following error message, `Could not find method compileOnly()` I am using gradle `2.3.3` , but when i am using `compile` it works fine, and loads jar files :)

Comment: Oh, if you are using **older** version of gradle plugin, then change `compileOnly` to `provided`. But, i suggest you upgrade your gradle plugin version to latest version, 3.2.1 to take its a number of advantages.

Comment: Thanks shizhen, this fixed my problem, but i am still unable to understand why external jar in a module are working fine in a new separate project without using `provided ` or `CompileOnly` keyword.

Comment: @Kirmani88, see my updated answer about the `provided` and `compileOnly`.

Comment: In the library I change from implementation to compile it started picking .jars file.