# Which Gradle version to use working in offline mode in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Are the gradle versions incompatible one to the other?

I am asking because I want to use the Offline Work setting in Adnroid Studio requiring a directory where to find the gradle files. But if I want to open an old project using another version of gradle, it does not work. Now I guess, I have to download all the versions I need and every time I switch the project, I need to also switch the gradle directory in the settings, right?

Or is it maybe possible to use just one version of gradle which also supports older versions?

Answer (score 0):

About gradle versions, you can cross check here: [What is real Android Studio Gradle Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391708/what-is-real-android-studio-gradle-version/51392464#51392464)

Each new gradle plugin version is not always designed to be compatible with the older once, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

> When you update Android Studio, you may receive a prompt to also update Gradle to the latest available version. You can choose to accept the update or manually specify a version based on your project's build requirements.
>   [image]