# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.4.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just turned on an old computer and am trying to access some code. After updating all of my Android Studio, JDK, and Downloading the latest Gradle I am having trouble building the project. I get this error ;

```
ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.4.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.4.1/gradle-5.4.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.4.1/gradle-5.4.1.jar
Required by:
    project :
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Open File
```

I have dont this and this

Below is the content of `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.4.1'
    }
}
```

Below is the content of wrapper file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

in my settings I have toggled between default and setting my path manually. I have also attemted to add `google()` and `MavenCentral()` to the repositories

I just ant to build and run my app but it is saying no! haha help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the best answers to your questions. Specifically, please improve your question's formatting and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open URL https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle, there is no 5.4.1.

For gradle version meanings, please check [What is real Android Studio Gradle Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391708/what-is-real-android-studio-gradle-version/51392464#51392464).

For your case, you need to add `google()` repo in your `buildscript` closure and modify the android-gradle-plugin version to be `3.4.1`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()// <-- add this. 
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    }
```

And, also, probably, you need to update your `allprojects` closure as below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()// <-- add this. 
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

---

**Edit #1**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

This is the wrapper configuration telling which gradle version to use for your android gradle plugin. It is **NOT** the plugin version.

Comment: Thank you for editing the Question! I will try these adjustments!

Answer (score 7):

Don't confuse gradle with the Android Gradle plugin.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.4.1'
```

It is the Android Gradle plugin and **5.4.1 doesn't exist**.

Use the latest stable release:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

[Check the release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) for other versions.

Comment: Testing now, Cheers!