# ERROR: Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

`build.gradle` is as below

```
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Error is as below:

> ERROR: Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 5.1.1.
>
> Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
> Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project
> Open Gradle wrapper properties
> Gradle settings

Comment: see [What are Android Gradle Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391708/what-is-real-android-studio-gradle-version/51392464#51392464) for more details.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The android gradle plugin and the gradle version are linked.
Here you can find [all info](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle):

```
Plugin version  Required Gradle version
1.0.0 - 1.1.3   2.2.1 - 2.3
1.2.0 - 1.3.1   2.2.1 - 2.9
1.5.0           2.2.1 - 2.13
2.0.0 - 2.1.2   2.10 - 2.13
2.1.3 - 2.2.3   2.14.1+
2.3.0+          3.3+
3.0.0+          4.1+
3.1.0+          4.4+
3.2.0 - 3.2.1   4.6+
3.3.0 - 3.3.2   4.10.1+
3.4.0+          5.1.1+
```

Use in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
```

and in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the gradle plugin version in your project level build.gradle file to 2.2.0:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
```

and then Invalidate and Restart Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Gradle in Terminal

```
gradle --version
```

if this is version 5.1.1 u have to set system environment variable to gradle 2.2.0

or check

```
gradlew --version
```

if this is version 5.1.1 it is enough to set

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
```

in your project level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Main thing I had to do to fix this error of trying to force going *backwards* for gradle was make sure when you change the gradle version in your file... you have to make sure that

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

are also in your dependencies so the correct sources are downloaded....

also you will have to change your plugin is in sync with whatever class you are including for gradle...